# Java: How can I disable clicking on a panel while showing dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jdialog

I want to disable clicking on the background panel or frame while showing a dialogue. And I want the dialogue to appear on top of this panel or frame constantly until it is closed.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not disable `Save` until the fields are non-empty?

Comment: +1 For the nicely described problem with screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make [Dialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html)/[JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) modal by calling `dialog.setModal(true);`. This will solve both issues of clicking background panel and remaining on top of panel.

---

It seems like this method is obsolete so better you should use `dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType type)`

Comment: Yes. Also note that the dialog's owner must be the frame or dialog to block. Look at the JDialog constructors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JOptionPane` for the message dialog.